keycloak Not authorized after succesful login through flask app
I wish to authenticate my flask app using keycloak as soon as i succesfully login with the user's credentials it is displaying "oauth2client.client.FlowExchangeError".
I am unable to fugre this out anyhow

I tried to alternate few settings in keycloak but it never helped
